# Using different version of lib through cocoapod for different project

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods, static-libraries

This is a tiny doubt which I want to get clarified.

I have a project which is lets say **Project-1** which uses a library of ytr (cocoapod version 0.1.13).

I have another project which is lets say **Project-2** which I am planning to use  library of ytr (cocoapod version 0.2.0).

Now if I do "**pod install**" in second project, will this also update the pod which is with "Project-1"?

Comment: does not here anyone who answer this question about  cocoapod?

Comment: You're a bit unclear... are Project-1 and Project-2 connected in any way?
Do they share the same Podfile or podspec?

Comment: no it is not and I am clear now.. there were no issue? thanks

Comment: ok i think i got you - see my anser

Answer (score 1):

When you run `pod install` it is in the context of the Podfile you are referencing. i.e. running `pod install` in the directory where Project-1 resides will install it's dependencies (and run whatever else you have defined in the podfile) for that Podfile under the `$PROJ1_PODFILE_LOCATION\Pods` directory

Doing the same for project-2 will install that project's dependencies under its own `$PROJ2_PODFILE_LOCATION\Pods` directory.

You can see the actual versions it downloaded for each project inside the `Podfile.lock` file it creates after resolving the dependencies (it's kinda like Gem's Gemfile.lock if you are familiar).

You can read more about this behavior and the `Podfile.lock` file [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#what-is-podfilelock)